# Why didn't I get a key error when the key does not exist?

Tags: python, dictionary, spyder, nonetype, keyerror

Assume I have an empty dict.

```
test_dict = {}
```

My original code is like this.

```
x = input()
try:
    info = test_dict.get(x)

except:
    print("Key Does Not Exist!")
```

but it doesn't raise a KeyError in my console, instead, it returns None. I am very sure I tested it and it works but after I updated my Spyder from 4.1.2 to 4.1.5, it doesn't work any more and I have to change my code to this:

```
x = input()
if x in test_dict.keys():
    info = test_dict.get(x)

else:
    print("Key Does Not Exist!")
```

Why does it return None instead of KeyError?

Comment: Because you used `.get`. That's what it's *supposed* to do, it's nothing to do with your IDE update. Also: 1. never use bare `except:`, be specific about what you're catching (in this case `except KeyError`); 2. you can test membership of a dictionary with just `x in test_dict`; and 3. you'd get a key error if you did `test_dict[x]` with a missing key.

Comment: Tq for telling me the 1. and 2. But it really does return NoneType when i dict.get(a non existing key)

Comment: Yes, I understand that; by using the get method that's what *you explicitly asked for*.

Comment: Oh.. i didnt see the test_dict[x] juz now. Okay. Tqvm

Comment: so i wont get a KeyError when i use the get method on a non existing key?

Comment: Well isn't that exactly what you've just demonstrated to yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not understand some behavior `help` can often be useful. In this case you can do:

```
test_dict = {}
help(test_dict.get)
```

to become aware that:

```
Help on built-in function get:

get(key, default=None, /) method of builtins.dict instance
    Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default.
```

Comment: thank you. I get it now and i learned a new functions too.